# Are there SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() functions or their equivalents that can be used in an MFC SDI application?

Tags: mfc, resize

I want to suspend redrawing while I'm resizing the main window. I have handlers in CMainFrame for OnEnterSizeMove() and OnExitSizeMove(), and thought I might be able to use SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() there, but these functions apparently don't exist in CFrameWnd or CWnd.

```
void CMainFrame::OnEnterSizeMove()
{
//  this->SuspendLayout();  (won't compile)
    CFrameWnd::OnEnterSizeMove();
}

void CMainFrame::OnExitSizeMove()
{
//  this->ResumeLayout(true);  (won't compile)
    CFrameWnd::OnExitSizeMove();
}
```

Thanks, SetRedraw() worked like a charm to stop redrawing. When I resize the window, redrawing stops, and when I stop resizing, the window redraws, BUT my custom toolbar doesn't redraw until I hover over each icon, when they reappear. Here's my code now:

```
void CMainFrame::OnEnterSizeMove()
{
    SetRedraw(FALSE);
    CFrameWnd::OnEnterSizeMove();
}

void CMainFrame::OnExitSizeMove()
{
    SetRedraw(TRUE);
    Invalidate();
    CFrameWnd::OnExitSizeMove();
}
```

Comment: `SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout` don't exist anywhere in MFC. They exist in the Windows Forms library. Those are unrelated. It's not immediately clear what you are trying to prevent here: Dynamic control layout, or repainting (as a result of control layout or otherwise). The former is manual, so you already have code you can change to accommodate for the desired behavior. For the latter, try [CWnd::SetRedraw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#setredraw), though I don't recall ever using it, so that may not work as desired.

Comment: Thanks, SetRedraw() worked like a charm to stop redrawing. When I resize the window, redrawing stops, and when I stop resizing, the window redraws, BUT my custom toolbar doesn't redraw until I hover over each icon, when they reappear. See above, I've added the code.